# React route with parameter not functioning on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a React single page app with multiple routes nested under a header component:

```
render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route component={VisibleHeader}>
        <Route path="/" component={VisibleMainLayout} />
        <Route path="poll/:pollId" component={VisiblePollLayout} />
        <Route path="newpoll" component={NewPollLayout} />
        <Route path="login" component={LoginLayout} />
        <Route path="mypolls" component={VisibleMyPollsLayout} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </div>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('react-container')
);
```

**The issue is with the "poll/:pollId" route.**

Everything works fine if I navigate to root first, then click on a `<Link>`. But if I'm at a "poll/" URL and refresh, or try to navigate directly to a "poll/" URL, I get a blank page.

Refreshing and direct navigation work fine on the other routes.

The clues I have are:

I can see from my express server logging output that reloading "/poll/5794b84b7969540e1b370233" requests the URL "/poll/5794b84b7969540e1b370233" THEN requests the URL "/poll/main.bundle.js". "main.bundle.js" is the name of the Webpack bundle that's loaded in the HTML normally:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="react-container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.bundle.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

When this happens, the server responds with the main view, but this gets treated as the Webpack bundle (i.e. it's looking for js but gets HTML instead).

Then the browser console displays an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and the browser shows a blank screen.

Here's a snippet of my server code if it's helpful:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/api',  api);
app.use('/auth', auth);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  console.log('Request: [GET]', req.originalUrl);
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/views/main.html');
});

/**
 * Error Handling
 */

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('404');
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.sendStatus(err.status || 500);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port,  function () {
  console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

A live demo of the whole shebang is currently [here](https://voting-nrf.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: try  <script src="/main.bundle.js"></script>

Comment: Yea, so each route is loading the javascript relatively. You need to be absolute as Utro said. I had the same problem not long ago.

Comment: Thanks Utro and Gregg, this solved it. If you'll add your comment as an answer I'll mark this answered.